# What does the notation $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ mean?

Tags: polynomials, notation, finite-fields

What does $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ mean in terms of polynomials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means polynomials where the coefficients are from the field with three elements $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Comment: So that would mean that $0, 1, 2$ equal $3, 4, 5$, respectively?

Comment: @johnnymath sure, in $\mathbb{F}_3$, $0$ and $3$ are just different representations for the same element